# header redirect with include file

Tags: php, html, loops

I've looked around on here and couldn't locate any solution for my little problem.

I currently have this following IF statment

```
if($page==1) {
    $sql = "UPDATE page SET page='1' WHERE id=1";
          INCLUDE 'month.php';
          header("Refresh: 10; url=http://XXXXX.co.uk/?p=2");           
    }
```

Which currently updates a database according to what page it is on and then includes the current month calendar file and I hoped I could redirect it to page number 2 which is very much similar but loads another calendar and the SQL adds +2 to the database.

In essence it's just a loop I've made and it just reads a SQL database to see what page it needs to load next< I know there's better ways to create a loop (just to scroll through 3 PHP pages) but I'm not that great at PHP..

So i'm just wondering really, could anybody help me to have that include statement along with the header refresh?

Like said the purpose is so that the pages rolls a loop, I've managed to get it all to work with an iframe (instead of the header) but it takes a few seconds longer for the frame window to load.

Comment: You'll have to embed the `Refresh:` header using `<meta http-equiv=..>` if it should work together with prior output. Else use a JS redirect.

Comment: Any reason you need to do it this way to refresh content instead of just using AJAX?

Comment: I'm fully open to ideas :) Unsure on how to get AJAX to reload the content (or at least 3 different pages / different PHP files)

@Mario I'll give that a test now mate :) cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

@Mario that's perfect - I echoed the following:

```
if($page==1) {
    $sql = "UPDATE page SET page='1' WHERE id=1";
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url= http://XXXXX.co.uk/?p=2"/>';
    INCLUDE 'month.php';
    }
```

Which now loads the loop flawlessly - I've been up all night trying to get that working.
Thank you so much

Can I push page transitions I wonder? 
Such as 'push out' or 'scroll out' ?